# convergence of product of sequences in $L^2$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, weak-convergence

> Let $\displaystyle (f_n)_n \subset L^\infty ([0,1])$,  $ \displaystyle
>  (g_n)_n \subset L^2 ([0,1]) $ and $\displaystyle f \in L^\infty
>  ([0,1]) $, $\displaystyle g \in L^2 ([0,1]) $ such that $\displaystyle
> f_n \to f $ almost everywhere, $\displaystyle \|f_n\|_{L^\infty} \leq C$, and $\displaystyle g_n \rightharpoonup g$ (i.e.   $g_n$ converges weakly to $g$ ).
>
> Show that $\displaystyle f_n g_n \to fg $ in $\displaystyle L^2
>  ([0,1]) $.

I would really appreciate some hints/ideas on how to start.

I know that I have to prove that $\displaystyle \int_0^1 |f_n g_n -fg |^2 \to 0 $...

Thanking in advance.

Answer (score 3):

This has no chance of being true as stated. You could take $f_n=1$ (all constant) and then it would mean that a weakly convergent sequence in $L^2$ is convergent in $L^2$, which is hardly true.

You may have better luck at showing that $f_ng_n$ converges weakly to $fg$. This follows from the fact that an almost everywhere convergent sequence in a finite measure space converges in measure (so it's enough to assume that $f_n$ converge in measure (in addition to being essentially uniformly bounded), and maybe not almost everywhere, or even anywhere at all).

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I will try that way.